# How to use WSGI with a Python/Flask App -- HasGeek Lastuser?

Tags: python, nginx, flask, wsgi, gunicorn

I am trying to setup a lastuser OAuth server on my machine. So I intend to setup Nginx with SSL ( on 443 ) and `lastuser` app as WSGI server.

[HasGeek lastuser](https://github.com/hasgeek/lastuser)

I have [setup HTTPS/SSL with Nginx](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-nginx-for-ubuntu-12-04) and it works fine on my machine.

However the WSGI server is not working.

Lastuser is basically a Flask app with a WSGI script `website.wsgi`.

```
import sys
import os.path
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(__file__))
from lastuserapp import app as application, init_for
init_for('production')
```

I tried using gunicorn for WSGI and I get the error `ImportError: No module named wsgi` as shown below:

```
$ gunicorn -b localhost:7000  website.wsgi 
2014-03-03 17:06:49 [31267] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 0.13.4
2014-03-03 17:06:49 [31267] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:7000 (31267)
2014-03-03 17:06:49 [31267] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2014-03-03 17:06:49 [31270] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 31270
2014-03-03 17:06:50 [31270] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 456, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 100, in init_process
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 101, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 24, in load
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/gunicorn/util.py", line 241, in import_app
    __import__(module)
ImportError: No module named wsgi
2014-03-03 17:06:50 [31270] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 31270)
2014-03-03 17:06:50 [31267] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2014-03-03 17:06:50 [31267] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

So my question is: is there anything I am doing wrong or is it an issue with gnunicorn or the libraries installed on my machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gunicorn is looking for a `wsgi` module inside a `website` module, which does not exist. This is why there is an identical `website.py` file in the same folder. Call that instead (without the `.py` extension).

`website.wsgi` is for use with Apache's `mod_wsgi` since that expects a `.wsgi` extension.

Comment: If you are using WSGIScriptAlias directive to configure mod_wsgi, it doesn't care what the WSGI script file extension is.

Comment: Interesting. So I can just knock off the redundant `website.wsgi` files from my repositories then?